# Read Excel file with two headers as a dataframe and generate a new header

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a Excel file with the file extensin .xlsx, which I read as dataframe by using the following code line

```
file = 'data.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file, engine='openpyxl')
```

The problem with this excel file is that it has two header lines, which looks simplified like:

[image]

As you can see the name of the datafields are not unique regarding revenues, see first header in row 3. Only in conjunction with the second header (row 5) the field name becomes unique.

What do I have to do in order to get a unique header, where I myself define the header name like the result below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['company1', 'company2'],
               'div_yield': [10.00, 2.57],
               'Market_Cap': [200, 5000],
               'Reven_2020': [20, 8963],
               'Reven_2019': [15, 5558],
               'Reven_2018': [10, 9332]})
```

At the end I wouldn't need the first 6 rows, so they could be skipped as long as I can get the result above.

Any suggestions? Ty in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think it can be the answer for your question, I get exact df as you wanted. Hope everything is good.

```
import pandas as pd
file = 'file.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file, engine='openpyxl',header = 2,skiprows = [3,4,5])
df=df.rename(columns = {'revenues':'Reven_2020','revenues.1':'Reven_2019','revenues.2':'Reven_2018'})
df
```

```
    Name      Market Cap    div_yield   Reven_2020  Reven_2019  Reven_2018
0   company1    200          10.00      20.000        15.000    10.000
1   company2    5000          2.57      8963          5558       9332
```